# Reset or clear selected values inside acf select

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a function that clear and set the new choices in select acf, is there a way to reset or clear also the selected values in admin field?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the choices for a select field under an ACF group in admin dashboard also.
You can use this [**acf/load_field**](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_field/)   filter to achieve that.

```
function my_acf_load_field( $field ) {
    $field['required'] = true;
    $field['choices'] = array(
        'custom'    => 'My Custom Choice',
        'custom_2'  => 'My Custom Choice 2'
    );
    return $field;
}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=custom_select', 'my_acf_load_field');
```